# Amount of Space required for Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I am about to partition my laptop for Ubuntu. I already have BackTrack partitioned on my computer. However, I recently heard that Linux does not need much space when partitioning because it will use other partitions for more space? Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is kind of true. But you want to be careful while doing this.

You can install Ubuntu on a partition as small as 4GB to run the OS and its essentials. Ubuntu / Linux can mount different partitions at mount points and work with NTFS partitions as well. If you have a windows data partition formatted with NTFS that you use for storing data, then you could make an entry in FSTAB to mount that partition in your Ubuntu at boot time.

However I will advise extreme caution if your Windows partition is system partition and contain Windows system files and boot partition before doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Optimal disk space is cca 10 Gb and SWAP.

Answer (score 1):

it depends what is the use of your Ubuntu.

Linux can mount other partitions and read and store information on them. But, To be able to do this and make it work. Your level in Linux should be pretty good.

As a beginner i would start with 20 GB.